# C point to next element (list)

Tags: c

My struct structure

```
struct Unit {
  int number;
  struct Unit *next;
};


int main(void) {
  struct Unit *head = build(5); /* Suppose that I have list of 5 units pointing to next one. Function build return the list */
  fn(head);
  printf("%d", head->number);
}
```

Is it possible to move to next element inside a function, like this?

```
void fn(struct Unit *head) {
  head = head->next;
}
```

Outside I still have pointer to first element after function calling.

Comment: `head` is passed by value, so you won't see any change you made in the function outside of it.

Comment: Change to `void fn(struct Unit **head) {
  *head = (*head)->next;
}` and Call `fn(&head);` But Perhaps it means memory leak.

Comment: Remember that pointers can be passed by value also (head poineter inside fn is just copy of Yours head pointer outside it)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: that's what I thought at first but the question appears not to be about that, and the answer would be "sure .. why do you believe it's not?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine (although the parameter name `head` becomes a bit misleading).  As you noted, iterating this way inside the function will not affect the `head` pointer outside the function call.